# Kanji for かまいあい?

Tags: kanji, compound-verbs

「最近【さいきん】の都会【とかい】にはお互【たが】いに面倒【めんどう】をみる『かまいあい』がなくなっちまったよな～」

*The "Kamai-ai" spirit of taking care of each other has disappeared in the cities these days.*

https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/column/henshu/20220224-OYT8T50049/

Could one write this word as 構【かま】い愛【あい】?

Comment: I believe it's 構い合い

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comment, it is 構い合い although it is more of an improvisation and not a common word.

あい here is a nominalization of あう, suffix meaning *each other*:

- 助け合う *to help each other* → 助け合い
- 話し合う *to have a talk (among people)* → 話し合い

Since 構う means *to take care of/look after*, 構い合い more or less means the same thing as the preceding お互いに面倒をみる(こと).